# SQL alchemy: Multiple select statements while iterating over result proxy set

Tags: sqlalchemy

SQL alchemy creates a unique `SELECT FROM WHERE id=id` lookup, for each model object in the results proxy set, which seems ineffective. Is this expected behaviour?

I have:

```
query = session.query(Model1, Model4).join(COMPLEX_JOIN_OVER_4_TABLES)
results = query.all()

for r in results:
    print(r.as_dict())
```

where `as_dict()` is a method of sql alchemy model class:

```
    def as_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

I pass `echo=True` to `create_engine()` to see that I'm executing a lot of SQL queries:

1. I make the complex join.
2. I then make multiple select statements, for each item in the resulted join, triggered by `as_dict()` method.

Why do I need to do that? The data should already be returned by the join.

Comment: I tried a simple join across three unrelated tables and the query and iteration generated only a single `SELECT`.  Can you share a [mre] that reproduces the behaviour that you describe?

Comment: Turns out this happens if I have `session.commit()` before the start of the iteration.